# biscuit conditional

Tags: conditionals

As I understand, a biscuit/relevance conditional is a conditional where an event in the main clause does not depend on whether an if-clause condition will be implemented or not. For example:

> **(1)**: *If you want to eat something tomorrow, there’s a food in the fridge*.
>
> **(2)**: *I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, if you want some*.

By this logic, I want to parse the next sentences:

**(3a)**: *I want/hope to visit the British Museum if I am in London*. - it's a biscuit conditional, since wanting/hoping to visit the British Museum is the desire which the speaker has even when they are not in London.

**(3b)**: *I **will** want/hope to visit the British Museum if I am in London*. - it's a "usual" conditional, since wanting/hoping to visit the British Museum is the desire which will appear only when the speaker has come to London.

Do you agree? Thanks!

Comment: No, there's something wrong with that. I'd say the equivalent would be: *If you want to when in London, you can visit the British Museum*. Your versions of the sentences rely on internal feelings as general statements, not objective facts.

Comment: Help in understanding biscuit conditionals can be found at  https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=24497. > *If you want to eat something tomorrow, there’s a food in the fridge* -  If you don't want to eat something, does this mean there is no food in the fridge?